# Laravel 5 multiple select() in query builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

In laravel 5.1, I want to do like

```
$myTable = MyTable->select('firstField');

if ($somethingTrue) {
    $myTable->select('secondField');
}

$myTable->get();
```

where I want both firstField & secondField to be selected.
Of course the code above is not working, i.e. only the secondField is selected in the end.

Is there any function provided by query builder class that can do exactly what I want?

Comment: Side note: `selectRaw` is automatically appended

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, you can use `addSelect()`

From the [Query Builder documentation under "Selects"](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#selects):

> If you already have a query builder instance and you wish to add a column to its existing select clause, you may use the addSelect method:

```
$query = DB::table('users')->select('name');
$users = $query->addSelect('age')->get();
```

Additionally, the [API documentation](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_addSelect) (as apposed to the written documentation) can also shed additional light on what functions are available on core classes.

Comment: this is exactly what I needed that you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Accepted answer is probably more elegant, but you could also just use an array of fields for your select clause.

```
$fields = ['firstField'];

if ($someCondition) {
    $fields[] = 'secondField';
}

$result = DB::table('users')->select($fields)->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

mwallisch's answer is better than accepted one because, if you have multiple places where you are defining selects then `addSelect` wont work.

For instance, following code will throw **error**:

```
$myTable = MyTable->select('firstField');

if ($somethingTrue) {
    $myTable->addSelect('secondField');
}

if ($somethingElseTrue) {
    $myTable->addSelect('thirdField');
}

$myTable->get();
```

while it can be done as:

```
    $fields = ['firstField'];

    if ($somethingTrue) {
       $fields[] = 'secondField';
    }

    if ($somethingElseTrue) {
        $fields[] = 'thirdField';
    }

    $result = DB::table('users')->select($fields)->get();
```