# Laravel Eloquent Multiple Select

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm just wondering if multiple select queries work in eloquent such as the code shown below

```
$sql = DB::('table')
        ->select('column1')
        ->selectRaw('raw select')->get();
```

Comment: Method chaining is possible but, why can't you select the required columns in a go?

Comment: "*I'm just wondering if multiple select queries work [...]*" You can always give it a try; see if it returns the results you're expecting. If you replace `->get()` with `->toSql()`, you can see (and test) the raw query that will be executed.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33472583/laravel-5-multiple-select-in-query-builder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 multiple select() in query builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33472583/laravel-5-multiple-select-in-query-builder)

Comment: I don't see any reasons to do that, if you need a raw select, you can simply add ,column after it